# Wrong postgres evaluation for plan rows

Tags: postgresql

We've encountered an issue where a query for some entities takes thousands of times longer. After analyzing, I came to the conclusion that the problem is that posgres expects the wrong 'plan rows' and therefore chooses a crooked algorithm. Estimated plan rows - 1, real - 10k. For most entities, evaluation works well.

What was also confusing: when trying to reproduce the problem locally, I did not succeed, postgres gives an acceptable score for all entities. So there is some problem in setting up the database? I also found that the index does not affect, the estimated quantity is still also 1.

For entities that work correctly:

[image]

that don't work right:
[image]

In this case, the simplest query SELECT * from table where id = ... is executed, I isolated it as an error from the rest of the query.

To understand what the problem is, I would like to understand how postgres calculates plan rows (did not find information on this issue) and some other tips on this case.

Comment: Have you seen [this](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/planner-stats-details.html)?

Comment: @mustaccio No =) Updating the stats did indeed fix the problem, it also explains why copying the schema locally didn't reproduce the problem. True, now the question arose why the statistics in the database turned out to be incorrect and how to avoid this in the future.

Comment: The default setting of autovacuum_analyze_scale_factor is 0.1.  So if you had a just-analyzed table with 1.1e6 rows but none of them had user_l=65, then inserting 100,000 rows with user_l=65 would not be enough turn over to trigger autovac to analyze the table, because 100000/1100000 < 0.1.  Is something like that actually happening?  I don't know, it is your database--you have to tell us.  If so, one solution would be to just manually VACUUM ANALYZE the table after such bulk inserts.